# Coin Tossing Game: Head/Tail Difference

Tags: probability

Consider this experiment:

A coin is tossed and the outcome of the toss recorded. If the outcome is heads the toss is given a score of $1$. If the outcome is tails the toss is given a score of $-1$. The coin is then tossed again and scores given in the same way, until the cumulative score of each toss gets back to $0$.

My questions are:

1. Is this game guaranteed to finish in a finite number of tosses (i.e. can it go on forever with the cumulative score never reaching $0$)
2. What is the expected length of the game?

So far I can see that each coin toss is an independent Bernoulli trial but the cumulative score after $k$ tosses depends on the cumulative score after $k-1$ tosses. I can't think of any distribution that could model the random variable of the cumulative score so could anyone give me some pointers about how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: For 1, yes it can go on in infinitum in theory. Consider only flipping heads.

Comment: The cumulative score after $k$ tosses only depends on the number of heads.  It will be twice the number of heads minus $k$.  After $k$ tosses the chance of score $n$ is precisely the chance you have thrown $\frac 12(k+n)$ heads.  It can go on forever, but will end in finite time with probability $1$

Comment: This is a standard random walk problem in one dimension. 
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk           The gist of it is that it will reach 0 an infinite number of times if you keep going.

Comment: Of course it _can_ go on forever -  it could happen  that you toss nothing but heads forever. But that's  not very likely - in fact it can be shown that _with probability $1$_ you do get back to $0$ at some finite time.

Answer (score 2):

### The game can take an arbitrarily long time—and on average, it *does* take an arbitrarily long time.

First, the game can go on arbitrarily long: if you flip a coin $n$ times, you may get $n$ heads in a row. As a result, the game can last longer than any number $n$ of turns.

Next, the expected length of the game is also infinite. To see this, let $x$ be the expected length of the game assuming the first throw is *heads*. Evidently, $x$ is also the expected length of the game assuming the first throw is tails, and it's also the expected length of the game overall.

We can get a formula for $x$ as follows. To play the game, you flip the coin once and get, say, heads. Now your score is +1. You flip the coin a second time. Either you get tails and win immediately (probability 1/2), or (probability 1/2) you get heads, your score goes up, and you must keep flipping coins until it gets back down to +1 again. The expected time it takes to get back to +1 starting from +1 is, of course, $x$.

Once you've returned to the score +1, you flip the coin again. You either get tails and win (probability 1/2), or your score goes up again, and you must keep flipping coins until it gets back down to +1 again, and ....

In formulas, the expected length of the game is:

$$x = \underbrace{1}_{\text{move right}} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(1)}_{\text{move left and win}} + \frac{1}{2}\left( \underbrace{x}_{\text{loop from +1 to +1}} + \frac{1}{2}\left[\underbrace{1}_{\text{left and win}} + x + \frac{1}{2}(\ldots)\right]\right)$$

$$x = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + x + \frac{1}{2}\left[1+x+\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + x + \ldots\right)\right]\right)$$

If we add $x$ to both sides, divide by two, and add one, we find that

$$1+x\; =\; 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + x + \frac{1}{2}\left[1+x+\frac{1}{2}\left(1 + x + \ldots\right)\right]\right) \qquad = x$$

so $x = x+1$. This problem occurs because the expected length is *infinite*— it exceeds all finite bounds.

---

We can see this result another way. The expected length of the game is:

$$x = \sum_{\text{winning sequence}} P(\text{sequence})\times\text{length}(\text{sequence})$$

Of course, a winning sequence of throws is any sequence of heads and tails with the same number of heads and tails. If $n$ is the number of heads in such a sequence, the length of the sequence is $2n$ and the probability of the sequence is $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$.  Also there are ${2n \choose n}$ winning sequences containing $n$ heads.

Hence

$$x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {2n \choose n }\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times 2n$$

which diverges to infinity.

Comment: Actually the probability that the length is $2n$ is smaller than $C(2n,n)/2^n$, because for some of the sequences you counted there you've already returned to the origin _before_ the $2n$th step.

Comment: I'm less certain, but it seems to me there's a similar overcounting problem with the first argument. Saying the expected number of times it takes to "loop back to $1$" is $x$ is including the times where you move from $1$ to the _left_ and then loop back to $1$; these sequences were already counted in the initial "move right" term.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're absolutely right I'm overcounting with $C(2n, n)/2^{2n}$. Though still divergent, the series is made of smaller terms.  For the first argument, I'm not sure what you mean.  To start with score +1 then return back for the first time, you initially either move from 1 to the left and stay on the left, or 1 to the right and stay on the right. By symmetry, both kinds of path have expected length $x$. Hence expected length, averaging over initial direction, is also $x$.  Does that resolve the question?

Comment: I think I'm convinced, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the first question, the game could technically go on "forever". No matter how many times (n) you flip the coin, there will be a $\frac{1}{2^n}$ chance of getting all heads or all tails as long as the coin is flipped a countable number of times. Thus you would have a score of $\pm n$ and not zero. However, as the comments have pointed out, if you really flip the coin a truly infinite number of times, then you must eventually get a score of 0.
As for the second question, I'm not sure. It would have to be an even number of turns so that the number of heads would equal the number of tales, but as the game goes on, you get less and less likely to "win". Flipping two coins gives a 50% chance of winning (HeadsTails or TailsHeads), but flipping four coins only gives a 37.5% chance (HHTT, HTHT, THHT, HTTH, THTH, TTHH). The chance of taking four turns to win is even less because in 4 out of those 6 scenarios you would have already won on the first turn. I would say the most common game length would be two turns, but the average game length would be closer to 6 or 8 turns.

Comment: why is average around 6-8?

Comment: It was just a guess, but I modeled it with a program, and it turns out that the mean of game lengths will be huge. The program plays 10000 games, but will quit a game if it takes more than 1000000 turns in the interest of time. Here's a link: https://jsfiddle.net/p74m1uzr/14/